# Multiple Dropdowns <Select> alignment to each other

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dialog box containing number of SELECT dropdowns. I have arranged them on the dialog by using &nbps;

However I am unable to place them correctly. Below is the image.

How to arrange them so that all these dropdowns would be vertical align to each other.

Regards.

Comment: Where's the image? What code did you try yourself? Can you make a JSFiddle please...??

Comment: `display:inline-block` may help?

Comment: Here is the image:  https://misbahmalik.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/html-select-dropdown-alignment/ .... I have tried inline-block but nothing happened :/

Comment: You can use table for this

Comment: not that much bebas ... I ll find the solution

Comment: @: Divyesh Savaliya: Thanks, your answer solved the problem. here is my dialog now... https://misbahmalik.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/solution/

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `&nbsp;` set the **min-width for label** and **set the width for select box**

For example:

Style:

```
.the-d-box{
clear:both;
margin:0 10px;
}
.the-d-box label,.the-d-box select{
float:left;
}
.the-d-box label{
width:120px;
}
.the-d-box select{
width:150px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="the-d-box">
    <label>Info</label>
    <select>..</select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what happened when I applied the above style: https://misbahmalik.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/remove/

Comment: css not applied that. Did you see in inspect element for it?